# How to fix text extending out of the bottom of a div element

Tags: html, css

I've cut down the code to the bare minimum: it seems that setting the font-size and line-height properties to a px value causes a different value to be used in practice.

In this example, the div is set to 77px height, and so is the font-size and line-height.  However, the actual letter is drawn using a glyph inside a height of 85 pixels.

Any ideas how I can make that letter draw inside a height of 77 pixels?

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  color: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 77px;
  line-height: 77px;
  font-size: 77px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>Q</div>
```

The actual height and width of the div are going to change according to the viewport size, so I don't have fixed numbers beforehand.

UPDATE: To be clear, the specific problem here is that I can't find a way to render a glyph at a specific pixel height.  Certain fonts will take the font-size (even when specified as a px value) and treat it as a suggestion, and render their character with a bunch of extra paddings and stuff, so in my example here, a Verdana glyph set to font-size 77px actually takes up 85 pixels in height - and that's only in Safari, I haven't yet worked out how other browsers and platforms will render it.

What I need, is to find out either how to figure out the true height a glyph will be rendered at, or figure out how to make it render at the exact height I specify.

So far, all I can do is to cut down the font-size by a 'small amount' and hope that'll work for all fonts at all sizes, and currently that amount seems to be ~0.75 of the actual pixel height that I would like to render it at.  The same is true for line-height, with the added complication that reducing that too much renders the glyph too high in the div, overlapping the top instead of the bottom.

Is there no way to specify the actual pixel height of a glyph?  Or no way to interrogate a font and find out what actual values it's going to use?

Comment: You want the text to dynamically fit inside the 'div'?

Comment: Is this "glyph" an image? ..

Comment: I calculate the size of div based on how many I need to fit on the page at one time, and I need the single letter text to fit entirely within that div.  Trouble is, I can't work out how to specify the font-size so that it will fit.

Answer (score 1):

Text elements include space at the top and at the bottom making up the line height. When you are setting the line height to the same size of the font, it does not make the space at the top smaller, but just means that the next line will then move up closer.
In order to remove the space at the top then, you could make the line height smaller than the font size. I played around and came up with a line height of 60px against your font size of 77px.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  color: red;
  height: 77px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 77px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.wrapper2 {
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  color: red;
  height: 77px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  font-size: 77px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.wrapper3 {
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">Q</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper2">Q</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper3">Q</div>
```

Comment: That's great for this specific case of div size, but if that changes, how can I figure out what line-height I should use then?  Since I don't know the size of div, and it could be literally anything, I need a way to calculate the numbers, not just manually working it out.

Comment: I get that your div will change size according to view port, but will your font size also be changing? If so, you can use a number to calculate your line height instead of using a fixed px height. If you set the line height to 1, then the line height is calculated to be the font size multiplied by 1. I've modified the above snippet with 2 examples where the line height is set to 0.8, calculating the line height to be smaller than the font-size. The third example shows a smaller div. However, if your font size is always a fixed 77px, then it will always overflow when the div gets too small.

Comment: I need to keep the letter inside the div at all viewport sizes, so yes, the exact problem is that I can't find an exact, *correct* way of figuring out what font-size to use, in order to draw a letter at an exact pixel height.  With your example, using a line-height multiple is great except that the value of 0.8 only works for certain fonts at certain sizes; and there's no way I can find to come up with a number that will guarantee it works.  Too short a line-height and the letter overlaps the top of the div; too large and it overlaps the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the letter have a small empty space at top as part of it, probably thats your problem.

Maybe you can take the letter inside a span tag and give these propierties to 'correct' this:

```
<div class=wrapper><span>Q</span></div>
```

and then:

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  color: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 77px;
  line-height: 77px;
  font-size: 77px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  position:relative; /* Positioning parent*/
}

span{
  position:absolute;
  top:-9px;
  left:8px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRbGpE

Comment: The problem is not that I can't make the letter fit, it's that I can only do it if I work out what the offsets should be before I run the program: and I can't do that because the div size can change to anything.